Must all French bank accounts be reported in the US FBAR?
I wonder the following: Must all French bank accounts be reported in the US Foreign Bank Account Report (FBAR)?
Assume that the combined value of the foreign financial accounts exceeds 10,000 USD at any point during the calendar year (since if less than 10,000 USD, no need to do FBAR).

What made you wonder?

@littleadv heard it's not needed for some accounts

Well, https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/report-of-foreign-bank-and-financial-accounts-fbar seems pretty clear. If you feel it is not, I suggest asking for professional help from a tax attorney well versed in such matters.

@JonCuster+ also, as linked there, https://www.irs.gov/businesses/comparison-of-form-8938-and-fbar-requirements lays out the differences between FATCA reporting and FBAR reporting, which many people find confusing

@FranckDernoncourt "Why the downvotes?" Because the question – posted 12 hours before your self-answer – showed no signs of you having done any research into the subject. If you were intending to self-answer, you should, in my opinion, have posted both Q and A at the same time.

@TripeHound thanks, point taken but many, if not most questions here  show no signs of OP having done any research and are typically not downvoted for that.

@littleadv Most of my questions are not trivial questions, e.g. here you've learned that some banks send FATCA reports to customers. The author of the answer doesn't matter and self-answers are explicitly allowed.

@littleadv Not trivial to me that FATCA doesn't report all accounts, and that FBAR accounts!=FACTA accounts.

All foreign bank accounts have to be reported. There's absolutely no reason to wonder, no relationship to FATCA, and nothing to do with tangible or real assets.
See 31 CFR 1010.350. The exceptions listed there are relevant to military personnel using dedicated military banking facilities, government entities, and banks themselves. Also note that not only accounts you own must be listed, but also accounts where you have signature authority.
The $10K threshold is for the total value of foreign accounts at any given time during the year. If for example you moved $5K between two accounts and the debit posted later than credit you'd have $10K aggregate balance even though you only actually have $5K there.

https://help.taxesforexpats.com/en/articles/6573327-france-specific:

French financial assets exempt from FBAR/FATCA reporting are limited to Social Security, Real Estate Holding, precious metals held directly, and collectibles.

From my reading of https://www.irs.gov/businesses/corporations/basic-questions-and-answers-on-form-8938, these exceptions apply to all countries and not just France:


No. Directly held tangible assets, such as art, antiques, jewelry, cars and other collectibles, are not specified foreign financial assets.

Directly held precious metals, such as gold, are not specified foreign financial assets. Note, however, that gold certificates issued by a foreign person may be a specified foreign financial asset that you would have to report on Form 8938, if the total value of all your specified foreign financial assets is greater than the reporting threshold that applies to you.



Aside from this, all other asset/accounts must be reported on FBAR.
Note that FACTA reporting (i.e., what French funds/entities need to report) have different requirements. Some accounts don't need to be reported. The Agreement Between The Government Of The United States Of America And The Government Of The French Republic To Improve International Tax Compliance And To Implement FACTA  contains the list of French bank accounts that do not  need to be reported by asset/accounts in the FACTA:

III. Accounts Excluded from Financial Accounts.
The following accounts and
products established in France and maintained by a French Financial Institution are excluded from the definition of Financial Accounts and therefore are not treated as U.S. Reportable Accounts:
A. Certain Retirement Accounts or Products

Products called « Article 82 » , « Article 83 », « Madelin, “Madelin
agricole”, “Perp, Pere and Prefon”
Products called « Article 39 »

B. Certain Other Tax-Favored Accounts or Products
Regulated savings accounts:

Livret A and Livret Bleu
Livret de Développement Durable
Livret d’Epargne Populaire
Livret Jeune
Plan d’Epargne Logement and Compte d’Epargne Logement
Plan d’épargne populaire / PEP

Employee savings accounts:

Accords de participation
Plan d’épargne d’entreprise / PEE and Plan d’épargne
interentreprises / PEI
Plan d’épargne pour la retraite collectif / PERCO and Plan
d’épargne pour la retraite collectif interentreprises / PERCOI
Compte courant bloqué


Also, from https://help.taxesforexpats.com/en/articles/6573327-france-specific, note that some types of funds/entities are exempt from FATCA reporting (i.e., they don't have to report FACTA), but the individuals must still add these funds/entities in their FBAR if required:

Retirement funds (Caisses de retraites) and similar financial entities (Caisses de congés payés) are exempt or deemed FATCA compliant because they are considered to present a low risk of being used by U.S. persons to evade U.S. taxes.
Even though specific retirement plans are exempt from direct FATCA reporting, the FATCA rules applying to individuals were not relaxed. Form 8938 requires reporting by U.S. taxpayers participating in foreign pension plans.


The only part of your answer relevant to the question now is "all ... accounts must be reported on FBAR". Everything else is a completely irrelevant content to beef up your answer to fill the space. There's no value whatsoever in any of it.

@littleadv: FATCA requires both reporting by foreign (non-US) financial institutions (more than just banks) and some non-FFIs as well, AND ALSO reporting by the US individual taxpayer on 8938. FBAR/BSA is indeed different, and requires reporting by the US accountholder -- whether or not subject to income tax -- of only FFI accounts but with a much lower threshold.

@littleadv Very useful for someone receiving FACTA reports from their banks, so that they're aware that FBAR may need more accounts

@FranckDernoncourt what FATCA reports are you receiving? Never gotten any. FBAR needs all the accounts, that was your answer. Anything else is irrelevant.

@littleadv some French banks send customers a copy of the FATCA reports.
